# SSIS not importing TEXT column from Excel correctly (integer results in NULL value)

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, ssis, import-from-excel

I have Excel 2003 files which are imported through SSIS into SQL 2008 R2. With one of the columns I hit a big problem. The column is defined as TEXT in the Excel sheet. Out of 36 rows 32 are having values like XTZ23, they get import correctly. The last 4 rows however
are just numbers like 2646672. They are imported as NULL. If I change the connection String to IMEX=1 and modify the registry to `TypeGuessRow=0` these numbers end up like 2.64667e+006.

What did I miss here?

Comment: must they stay excel files? if you save them as csv you can use a schema.ini to define the datatype.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but for future searchers, just add IMEX=1 into the connectionstring of your Excel manager in the SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

First solution would be to change excel column format if possible.
Second, I have had this problem 2 years ago, excel file couldn't be changed since I was getting it from another service ... I can`t remmember correctly but I have called custom code/function or it was some sort of transformation inside SSIS that was converting specific column rows from one data type to another.